# UIScrollView not updating

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView that contains a bunch of subviews. If the view is initially loaded in landscape or portrait the layout of each is fine. However, when I try to deal with orientation changes nothing happens.

What I believe to be the issue is that the subviews frames are being updated, but not re-drawn.

I am using this as of now to set the frames on an orientation change:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation      duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    int i = 0;
    for(UIView *subview in [scroll subviews]) {
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[GalleryThumbContainerView class]]) {
            [subview setFrame:[self getFrameLandscape:i]];
            i++;
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

If the device is in portrait and I rotate it to landscape none of the subviews new frames are updated.

If I keep the device in portrait and leave the view, then come back all the new frames are updated.

That leads me to believe that is some problem with the set not being updated. I have tried:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
[self.scroll setNeedsDisplay];
[self.scroll setNeedsLayout];
```

None of which work.

I have managed to "make" it work by:

1. Removing all the subviews of the scrollView
2. Setting all the subviews new frame
3. Re-Adding all the subviews back the scrollView

There seems a much cleaner way to do this.

I have also tried adding an orientation change listener to my subviews subclass (mouth full), and storing each subviews landscape and portrait frames. Then switching by the listener. Which this didn't work either.

Any help is very much appreciated and thank you for your time.

Comment: What about setting all your views' content mode to UIViewContentModeRedraw? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Comment: Are you resizing the ScrollView on the InterfaceOrientation change as well?

Comment: @H2CO3 no luck with that either.

Comment: Does this expression returns YES :[subview isKindOfClass:[GalleryThumbContainerView class]] and what is the purpose of i I assume just for counting purpose?

Comment: It iterates through all of the subviews of the scrollView that are of type GalleryThumbContainerView. If I didn't do that check it would go through all the subviews (system scroll bar, etc..).

Answer (score 0):

for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews)

```
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) 
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```